# How do I make my footer stay at the bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

How can I fix my footer and keep it at the bottom? I have tried `bottom:0;` and a few other things but no luck, what is the best method to achieve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/94wgz07s/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>A. Willi A.G - Fachkräft für Rohr-Stahl Gebäudetechnik</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="2.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/images/favicon.png"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner">
        <img src="/images/logo.png">
        </div>


<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/html/contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Info</a>
      <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    </div>
  </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
             <a href="/html/personnel.html">Personalverleih</a>
                 <a href="/html/rental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a>
                    <a href="/html/refrences.html">Referenzen</a>
                 <a href="/html/quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>


        <p>
            Die A. Willi AG ist als Personalverleiher mit über 35-jähriger Erfahrung in der ganzen Schweiz und im Ausland erfolgreich tätig. 
        </p>

        <p>
            Wir bringen erfahrene Arbeitskräfte und anspruchsvolle Kunden zusammen. Derzeit sind über 100 Arbeitnehmer für die A. Willi AG im Einsatz. 
        </p>



        <p>
           Wir haben uns spezialisiert auf dem Verleih von qualifiziertem Fachpersonal in den Bereichen Rohr – Stahl – Gebäudetechnik. Für die Beratung und Vermittlung sind in diesen Gebieten ausgewiesene Fachleute zuständig, welche als kompetente Partner mit unseren Kunden gemeinsam den Personaleinsatz planen.
        </p>


        <p>
            Unsere Kunden schätzen die hohe Qualität unserer Dienstleistungen und die auf langfristigen Erfolg und faire Partnerschaft ausgerichtete Strategie. 

        </p>

        <div class="image1">
        <img alt="A screenshot showing CSS Quick Edit" src="/images/3.png" width="100%" height="40%" />
        </div>

        </a>

        <p>
            Wir suchen laufend hoch qualifiziertes Fachpersonal mit ausgewiesener Berufserfahrung. Wir bieten ihnen, Faire Anstellungsbedingungen, kostenlose Arbeitsbekleidung und PSA Ausrüstung, Weiterbildung in Beruf und Sicherheit.
        </p>
        <p>
            Unsere Dienstleistungen verbessern wir kontinuierlich, um unseren Kunden einen Qualitativen, zuverlässigen und individuellen Service zu bieten.
        </p>


        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>

        <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>


        <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>

        <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>


        <div id="content_footer"></div>
         <div id="footer">
         <p><a href="index.html">&copy; A.Willi A.G</a> | <a href="examples.html">Wasgenring 94</a> | <a href="page.html">CH-4055 Basel</a> | <a href="another_page.html">admin@awilli-ag.ch</a> | <a href="contact.html">Kontakt Aufnehmen</a></p>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
html {
    background: lightgrey;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}

body {
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 2em 0.5em 4em;
}



h2 {
    margin-top: 1.3em;
}




samp {
    display: none;
}

img {
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}




ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-top: -2%;


}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #333;
 color: darkgray;
  text-decoration: none;}


li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}



#banner {
    margin-top: -8%;
    width:100%;
    min-height:189px;
}


#footer
{ width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 28px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center; 
  background: #333;
  border-top: 2px solid #333;
  color: #FFF;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

}

#footer p
{ line-height: 1.7em;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;}

#footer a
{ color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;}

#footer a:hover
{ color: darkgray;
  text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: use `position:fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

If by bottom you mean remove that spacing.

Remove the `bottom: 0;` and add `position: absolute;`

If not, then like Ron Basco said, use `position: fixed;`and adjust your padding to something more along `padding: 2em 0.5em 9em;`